# Translation of a probably old German childrens verse "Soli, soli, soli..."

Tags: german-to-english

I have been searching for an answer to this old dialect of German but to no avail.  Has anyone ever heard an older generation say:

> “Soli soli soli Meiner liebe drolli“

My grandmother used to gently pat out foreheads when we were hurt and say this.  I believe what she was saying was “there there there little one it’s okay” but a literal translation doesn’t work. My mother was born in Germany and my fiancé was too, but neither know the real translation. Has anyone heard?

We are all from the Black Forest (Baden Baden) if that helps with dialects!

Comment: Could you add information when (what year, approximately) your ancestors left the Black Forest region, and where they went? - Also, does your mentioning of the town of Baden Baden mean that they came from there, or a village nearby?

Comment: Maybe you can also find out where your grandmother originally came from (many Sudeten Germans settled in this area)

Comment: DWDS links to a Grimm entry for _droll_. Not sure, whether it is relevant for _drolli_, but in case someone wants to do more research here: https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/droll

Comment: Related: [Heile, heile Gänsje](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heile,_heile_G%C3%A4nsje)

Comment: Vom Anlaut würde es als Kinderreim plausibler klingen, wenn es nicht "Soli, soli, meiner Liebe drolli" sondern "Solli, solli, meiner Liebe drolli" (evtl. "Soll i, soll i (soll ich)) oder "Soli, soli, meiner Liebe droli" hieße.

Comment: Could you add a recording of this? The rhythm in which it is pronounced could change a lot. it could e.G. be actually something like "Soliso Lisoli" and when I ask someone from the region here it would be easier if I could pronounce it as your grandmother had.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it helps, but a common - and not unsimilar - phrase (or verse) used in such situations is

> Heile, heile Segen
>   drei Tage Regen
>   drei Tage Sonnenschein
>   's wird bald wieder besser sein.

Note that this is positively used in South and South-West Germany, so covering the area you mentioned.

**Some ideas contributed in comments**

This answer (or non-answer) received valuable feedback from commenters, partly with new creative attempts to explain the wording. I summarize and comment the thoughts refering to the enigmatic word "soli":

1) Soli = Segen?

Marzipanherz asked: Is there a south/southwest German form of *Segen* that sounds similar to Soli? My answer: I do not see a lexical relation between *Segen* and soli in German or a German dialect.

2) Soli = solacium?

One thing I was pondering is if *soli* here could be derived from Latin *solacium* (= *Trost* = comfort, solace), as Latin was broadly used in catholic churches up to the 1960s. But that's a very far-fetched idea. Villagers did not usually integrate Latin terms they heard in church into their everyday vocabulary. Famous exceptions are *sacramentum* and *crucifixum* which both are used as curse words (*Sakrament! Kruzifix! Zefix!*). But I have never met such a Latin church derivative in nursing rhymes.

3) Soli = sodele?

Beta said: Could *soli* be a diminutive form of "so" (as in *södele* or *sodele*), which would fit perfectly in a comforting situation. My answer: I am not sure about this idea. Having grown up in the Swabian South-West (with part of my family being farmers and active users of dialect) I first thought: no, seeing "soli" as  representation of "sodele" does not make sense. On second thought, however, one could indeed imagine that there once was a verse like "Sodele, sodele, sodele" which got distorted over time by users of the language detached from the area (emigrant-settlers to Eastern Europe in 18th century?).

Or perhaps the grandmother said actually "sodele", but Emma (who asked) just wrote it down as "soli" because she is not aware of a word "sodele"?

4) Soli = soll ich?

Somebody suggested that *soli* could stand for *soll ich* (shall I / should I) . My opinion: the words taken isolated, yes, this makes sense. Written *soli* would be pronounced quite similar to what speakers of South-West German dialects say for "soll ich". However, I struggle to fit "soll ich" into the context of the nursery rhyme.

---

PS: A short search with one of our preferred look-stuff-up machines brought this variant of the same nursery rhyme:

> Heile, heile Segen
>   sieben Tage Regen,
>   sieben Tage Sonnenschein,
>   wird alles wieder heile sein.
>   Heile, heile Segen,
>   sieben Tage Regen,
>   sieben Tage Schnee,
>   tut dem Kind schon nicht mehr weh.

Comment: Are you aware of a south/southwest  German form of _Segen_ that sounds similar to _Soli_?

Comment: ... but *solacium* did not make it into everyday language, as far as I could observe.

Comment: The _solacium_ part is interesting. However, I'm a bit lost now about the connection between the question and your answer, since it didn't ask for comforting rhymes in general, but about a specific one.

Comment: Couldn't "soli" be a  diminutive form of "so" (as in "södele"), which would fit perfectly in a comforting situation.

Comment: @Marzipanherz   I do not really believe that "Soli, soli, soli" in the quoted verse is related to (church) Latin *solacium*. If we however for the sake of the argument just suppose that there is a connection, it would make perfect sense, because the quoted verse is used in order to solace (!) a child that had hurt itself.

Comment: PS: But then, "sodele" does not rhyme with "drolli" - whatever *drolli* might be, because that's the next riddle here. - Actually the entire sentence does not make sense, not a single part of it; the only thing that makes sense is the general social situation where some verse like this is plausible to be used. But the wording here is irritating.

Comment: Mein erster Gedanke zu "Meiner liebe drolli" war, dass es eine falsch verstanden Version von "Mein lieber Scholli" ist, was ja im Badischen hinlänglich bekannt ist. Das reimt sich zwar auf "soli", was auch immer das dann sein soll. Aber vielleicht muss sich "Sodele, sodele, mein lieber Scholli" auch gar nicht reimen?

Comment: @IQV  Ich kenne "Mein lieber Scholli" nur in ermahnender oder gar drohender Verwendung, nicht im Kontext vom Spenden von Trost und Geborgenheit. Insofern passt es hier nicht recht zum sozialen Kontext.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Maybe _drolli_ is derived from _droll_ - I have posted a link to DWDS/Grimm below the question

Comment: My only thoughts on this are that *drolli* could be derived from *drollig*, some strange substantivation and that *soli* is just wrong, maybe *so wie*, or even *sowieso* (whatever sense that would make)

Answer (score 0):

“soli soli soli” is a latin play of words, meaning something like “To the only sun of the earth”.

Soli #1 is the dative form of solus/a/um (only),
Soli #2 is the dative form of sol/solis (sun),
Soli #3 is the genitive form of solum/i (ground or earth).

I believe it was often used as an inscription on sundials.

Comment: Latin grammar in a children rime - that doesn't sound plausible. Planets with multiple suns aren't that prevalent, to attribute the sun as our only sun. This sounds like a made up answer.

Comment: @userunknown Baden-Baden ist nahe der französischen Grenze, "soli soli soli" wurde auch von Luis XIV ("Sonnenkönig") und später Napoleon benutzt. In der katholischen Bevölkerung war Latein gegenwärtig, gerade als obskures Gemurmel, das keiner versteht. Ich würde einen Spruch mit Küchenlatein nicht so einfach ausschließen.

Comment: @HalvarF: Es bildet sich aber keine Verbindung zu "meiner liebe Drolli", wobei nach wie unklar ist, ob es wie ein Reim klingen soll - dann müsste es ja "Solli" heißen oder "Droli", aber Emma hat nie wieder von sich hören lassen. Unverstandenes, lateinisches Gemurmel wird als Quelle für "Akrakadabra" vermutet, aber das kommt in der lateinischen Messe auch vor, im Gegensatz zu "Soli soli soli". Die Bildung früher war spärlich gesäht, besonders auf dem Land, und alt muss es ja sein, wenn es heute keiner kennt.

Comment: @userunknown It might not be relevant, and my translation might be awkward, but my answer is not a “made up answer”. As HalvarF points out, “soli soli soli“ is an established phrase known and seen throughout Europe for hundreds of years. A children’s rhyme – a nonsense rhyme – is often more about sound and sensation than clear sense or logic. Latin still pervades German language and culture, and in past centuries much more so, regardless of how many actually studied the language.
As for “Drolli”: connected to “drollig” (drôle) nominalised? i.e. “my dearest little funny one“.

Answer (score -2):

This must be something local... never heared something like that.

Soli = Usually used as acronym for "Solidaritätszuschlag" (a special reunion tax)
I guess its something else, becasue the Soli exists only since 1990.

If "drolli" is a name it must be "Meine liebe" (if drolli is female) or "Mein lieber" (if drolli is male)

edit: "Soli" could be a short version of "Soll ich" -> should I.

This would make sense... its a question "Should I, Schould I, should I my dear drolli"

Comment: A bit meager for an answer, if you leave out all the speculation...

Comment: Although it is technically correct that "Soli" is a word used for a certain tax officially called *Solidaritätszuschlag*, it would not come to my mind to mention this with regard to a grandmotherly nursery rhyme.

Comment: @Robert I dont think that anybody can answer this question correct, it sounds like an ancient local dialect and propably it is written wrong. So I would be thankful for any hint in what direction it could go.